# Load DLL reference only when needed?

Tags: vb.net

I have a managed DLL i created (checks file hashes).
However, my intention is to use it only when it's actually detected by a
My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists check (it is distributed separately), otherwise, the DLL function isn't called.

How can I do this without the program complaining about a missing reference when the
DLL isn't there?

This is the calling line:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Addin.dll") Then
        If AddIn.CheckOps.Checking.CheckLibHashes = False Then
            MsgBox("Cannot load the Commercial Addin. Error message: bad file checksum" & vbCrLf & "Please re-install program and the Addin.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Else
            CommercialToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
        End If
    Else
        CommercialToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
    End If
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not add Reference to DLL in your Project.
What you need is Dynamically Loading a managed DLL.

If your DLL exist then load it using

```
System.Reflection.Assembly oMyDLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(szDLL_FilePath);
```

[Reference (System.Reflection.Assembly)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile(v=vs.100).aspx)